# How to use str_split() function for printing string character by character

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

there is a table named 'students' and I want to print all datas out, there is no difficulty in it, but for some reason I have to print 'Name' and 'Family' columns character by character in table.I know I should use str_split but don't know how to use it .
thnx in advance.

this is my controller:

```
  $students = DB::table('students')->select('*')->get();
```

[image: should be like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to print the attributes out after passing students into a blade file then try this:

```
// An example to display the `name` field inside a table, do the same for the family field
<table>
  ...
  @foreach($students as $student)
    ...
    <tr>
      @foreach(str_split($student->name) as $character)
        <td>{{ $character }}</td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    ...
  @endforeach
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can defined [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators) to split the characters:

```php
    protected $appends = ['name', 'family'];

    public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return str_split($value);
    }
    public function getFamilyAttribute($value)
    {
        return str_split($value);
    }
```

However, you need to use Eloquent-builder instead of query-builder:

```php
Student::select('*')->get();
```

Comment: thanks for replying.I know I should work with mutator but for some reason I can't. but thnks anyway